# Docker friendlyhello app exec: "docker-proxy" and port binding errors

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker.  I'm following the instructions on the [friendlyhello tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app).  I'm running this on a CentOS 7.5 virtual machine, `docker --version` is 1.13.1.  I get to the point where I run `docker run -d -p 4000:80 friendlyhello` and get :

```
$ docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint eager_dijkstra (f022a7a52040c54a54d94270e94a4149554be38514c88cb933d77440f43f6092): exec: "docker-proxy": executable file not found in $PATH.
```

If I run it again :

```
$ docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint amazing_wiles (cfb767520e0f130d93cb881917320555ea3eccd605dd845b978e062e1aca3b57): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4000 failed: port is already allocated.
```

I do not have a `docker-proxy` executable on my machine.

**QUESTION** :

1. How do I get friendlyhello to run?  Where is `docker-proxy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently I installed docker through just the default yum repos, e.g. `yum install docker`.  This got me `docker version 1.13.1`.  This is incorrect (and non-intuitive), I needed to install it following these [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-from-a-package) from the docker website.  This got me `docker-proxy` and allowed  me to run the `friendlyhello` example (`docker version 18.06.1-ce`).  Reposting the instructions :

```
## Clean up my previous install
$ sudo yum remove docker \
                  docker-client \
                  docker-client-latest \
                  docker-common \
                  docker-latest \
                  docker-latest-logrotate \
                  docker-logrotate \
                  docker-selinux \
                  docker-engine-selinux \
                  docker-engine

$ sudo yum install -y yum-utils \
  device-mapper-persistent-data \
  lvm2

### This is the repo to get the correct docker distribution
$ sudo yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

$ sudo yum install docker-ce
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced exact same issue. 
Removing docker completely and installing from official website solved my issue. 
[Offical Link](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/)